# Generating GeoTiff using Geopandas/GeoPlot

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, geotiff, geoplot

I have generated a plot with GeoPandas/GeoPlot and now need to upload this as a georeferenced image into some software that only takes GeoTiffs.

I have spent a significant amount of time trying to find a way of doing this but without any luck.

So, if anyone could explain how I could take GeoPlot output generated from a GeoPandas DataFrame and turn it into a GeoTiff, I would really appreciate it?